# PHP script and MS Access database through ODBC connection

Tags: php, database, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I want to connect a web-server with PHP-Script and MS Access database.
Both are on the server and I only need an ODBC connection.

Does that mean that server does not support ODBC connections?

Is there an alternative solution to my problem. How to match PHPscript with ms access database on the web server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: instal odbc driver, add extension to php.ini and use pdo

Comment: How can I install drivers on an external web hosting server ?

Comment: do you have remote access to the server?

Comment: yes i have an access

Comment: then connect to the server and setup everything

Comment: Thanks i will try ;)

Comment: @Zeljka unfortunately my web hosting does not support an ODBC link.
iIf you know alternatives i will be very happy or at worst case i will need to change the webserver hosting ;(